# How to identify the route being called in a RSpec controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an RSpec controller spec and I'm trying to understand how to find what exact route is being called in my example.

In services_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe 'create comment' do
  let!(:service) { FactoryGirl.create(:service) }

  describe 'with valid comment' do
    it 'creates a new comment' do
      expect {
        post :add_comment, id: service.id
      }.to change(service.service_comments, :count).by(1)

      expect(response).to redirect_to(service_path(service))
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to `pp` or `puts` the route that is being sent via the post?

I am asking because I want to `post` to the route `/services/:id/add_comment` and want to verify where exactly the route is going.

My routes.rb for this route:

```
resources :services do
  member do
     post 'add_comment'
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help to show the `describe ServicesController` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the name of the route used in an rspec-rails controller spec with something like this:

```
routes.formatter.send(
  :match_route,
  nil,
  controller: ServicesController.controller_path,
  action: 'add_comment', # what you passed to the get method, but a string, not a symbol
  id: service.id         # the other options that you passed to the get method
) { |route| puts route.name }
```

rspec-rails uses the route only internally. The above is how rspec-rails (actually `ActionController::TestCase`, which rspec-rails uses) looks up and uses the route, but with a block that just prints the route.

There are a lot of method calls between the `post` call in a spec and the above, so if you want to understand how rspec-rails gets to the above I suggest putting a breakpoint in `ActionDispatch::Journey::Formatter.match_routes` before running your example.

Note that an rspec-rails controller spec doesn't use the route to decide what action method to call or what controller class to call it on; it already knows them from the controller class you pass to `describe` and the action you pass to the action method (`get`, `post`, etc.). However, it does look up the route and use it to format the request environment. Among other uses, it puts the path in `request.env['PATH_INFO']`.

I investigated this in Rails 4.1, since that's what the project I have handy uses. It might or might not be accurate for other versions of Rails.

Comment: I tried to run the code you provided above, but got an error saying `undefined method: formatter'. Thoughts? Do I need to import anything new? Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: What versions of Rails and rspec-rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.1.8
Rspec 3.4.4

Comment: Strange. It works for me with Rails 4.1.8, and I'm using the same version of RSpec. What does `puts routes.class` say? Or `puts routes.methods`? Or `puts routes.private_methods`?

Comment: I ran those commands and looked for `formatter` method but couldn't find it. I did however find a `format` method, but it's a `private_method`  <br/> `puts routes.class` yields `Array`

Comment: My `routes.class` is `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet`, returned by [an rspec-rails controller spec method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb#L132). What could we be doing differently? Does `Rails.application.routes` work?

Comment: What's weird is, when I follow the deceleration of `routes` it also leads me to the same controller_example_group.rb.   

When I `puts` `Rails.application.routes.class`, I get `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet`  

I used the explicit deceleration and it worked. I can see the route it is calling. Thanks for the help!